# Скачать файл с сервера

Tags: javascript, blob, save

Отправляю запрос на сервер и получаю в ответ объект:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

И я пытаюсь сохранить этот файл таким способом

```
let FileSaver = require('file-saver');
let file = new File([res.body.uri], "hello world.js");
 FileSaver.saveAs(file);
```

И собственно файл сохраняется, но при открытии файла, его содержимое выглядет точно так же как res.body.uri - то есть

```
uri:"data:application/javascript;base64,alF1ZXJ5KGRvY3VtZW50KS5yZWFkeShmdW5jdGlvbigkKSB7CiAgICAkKCcucG
```

Что мне нужно сделать что бы файл сохранялся корректно? (я не знаю в каком расширении лижит файл на сервере)

Answer (score 1):

1. Получим из строки данные для конвертации.

   `[res.body.uri].split(",")[1];`
2. Используем функцию для конвертации в UTF-8

   ```
   function b64DecodeUnicode(str) {
       return decodeURIComponent(Array.prototype.map.call(atob(str), function(c) {
           return '%' + ('00' + c.charCodeAt(0).toString(16)).slice(-2)
       }).join(''));
   }
   ```
3. Сохраняем полученные данные

   ```
   let FileSaver = require('file-saver');
   let file = new File(decode_data, "hello world.js");
   FileSaver.saveAs(file);
   ```

Comment: А если я захочу сохранить документ word^ делаю все тоже самое?

Comment: В этом случае, скорее всего, придется конвертировать в Windows-1251.

Comment: Попробуйте `b64DecodeUnicode(str)` заменить встроенной функцией `atob()`